# Delaying activity start

Tags: android, android-activity

When a user enters an activity on my app I want to perform some logic during onStart and possibly launch a second activity before letting the user see the first activity (think of this as a pin protected activity)

I have a small issue where the contents of the first activity are shown for a second before the second activity is started. This happens when the user uses the home button to get out and in to the app.  Is there a way to prevent the first activity to be visible at all before performing the logic validation?

Comment: I haven't tried it but think will work. Add a variable to your first activity like `boolean Visible = false;`. then in `onResume()` check if that variable is `false` use `setVisibility(View.GONE)` on your `activity root view` and if `true` make it visible using `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a "design" solution to your problem and not clear if it'll work for you. I had something similar in the app I'm working on. What I did instead, was to create an interstitial Activity that resembled the same starting state (i.e. not yet completely loaded) of the Activity (Pin-protected Activity in your case) that is about to be started. Once I'd made my appropriate decision about whether or not I could go on, I just navigated to that initial Activity. In your case, I could see you making the decision on this interstitial Activity, and then navigating to the Pin-protected Activity or to the other one if conditions were not met properly.

The only downside to this approach is that the app does a quick flash with the additional Activity, but I think the increased separation of logic is worth it.